# Kubernetes Volume Mount ConfigMap to File within the pod without overwriting all other files

Tags: kubernetes, configmap

I have the following ConfigMap in my Kubernetes cluster that contains the `web.config` for my application there is a different one per environment so I would like to volume mount the ConfigMap to `web.config` in the pod.

**ConfigMap**:

```yaml
kind: ConfigMap 
apiVersion: v1 
metadata:
  name: stars-website-data-config
  namespace: stars-website
data:
  config: |-
    <?xml version="1.0"?>
    <configuration>
      ...
    </configuration>
```

**Deployment**:

```yaml
kind: Deployment
apiVersion: apps/v1
metadata:
  name: stars-website-data
  namespace: stars-website
spec:
  template:
    spec:
      containers:
        - name: stars-website-data
          ...
          volumeMounts:
            - name: config
              mountPath: C:\STARS.Website.Data
      volumes:
        - name: config
          configMap:
            name: stars-website-data-config
            items:
            - key: config
              path: web.config
```

This seems to do what I want it to do but it replaces all the other files and folder in that directory.

```
PS C:\STARS.Website.Data> ls 


    Directory: C:\STARS.Website.Data 


Mode                LastWriteTime         Length Name
----                -------------         ------ ----
d-----        5/14/2021  10:55 AM                ..2021_05_14_09_55_42.624339347
d----l        5/14/2021  10:55 AM                ..data
-a---l        5/14/2021  10:55 AM              0 web.config


PS C:\STARS.Website.Data> cat .\web.config
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<configuration>
        <configSections>
```

If I try to use the `subPath` value like:

```yaml
kind: Deployment
apiVersion: apps/v1
metadata:
  name: stars-website-data
  namespace: stars-website
spec:
  template:
    spec:
      containers:
        - name: stars-website-data
          ...
          volumeMounts:
            - name: config
              mountPath: C:\STARS.Website.Data\web.config
              subPath: web.config
      volumes:
        - name: config
          configMap:
            name: stars-website-data-config
            items:
            - key: config
              path: web.config
```

I am getting the following error:

```
Error: Error response from daemon: invalid volume specification: 'c:\var\lib\kubelet\pods\ddfe6b07-4bff-42fe-ad3b-a02add00fbbf\volumes\kubernetes.io~configmap\config\web.config:C:\STARS.Website.Data\web.config:ro': invalid mount config for type "bind": source path must be a directory
```

Comment: `subPath` has a different purpose, namely it allows you to share a single volume for multiple uses in a single pod. Take a look at the example in the [docs](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/storage/volumes/#using-subpath). So the error you get is expected. It clearly says "source path must be a directory" and you're refering to a single file. Overwriting the entire `mountPath` directory by what you're mounting from your volume is also expected behaviour.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When configMap is mounted as volume then it will delete all the files which were previously present in the mount path, this is expected behaviour. Please refer caution section in this [link](https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/configure-pod-container/configure-pod-configmap/#populate-a-volume-with-data-stored-in-a-configmap).

With respective to your subpath configuration, there is a limitation in bind mounting files directly for windows based container, please refer this [discussion](https://github.com/moby/moby/issues/30555).  The preferred approach is directory mounting for windows based container, you can create separate empty directory and you can mount your configmap to that directory which might be quick and straight forward solution.

This [link](https://artisticcheese.wordpress.com/2021/05/02/circumventing-windows-containers-limitation-on-volume-mounts/) has got workaround solution which might be useful for you.

There is one major disadvantage of using either subpath configuration or workaround solution given in the above link is whenever you update your configmap it would not automatically update the project key.

Thanks,

Comment: Thank you for you explanation.